# How to create a DSL tools project in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, vsix, vs-extensibility, dsl-tools

Anyone else having trouble creating a new dsl tools project in Visual Studio 2019?

I cannot find the "Domain-specific Language Designer" solution template (as is named in Visual Studio 2017) anywhere...

Although the official documentation references it unchanged here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/visualstudio/modeling/how-to-define-a-domain-specific-language?view=vs-2019

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, the template is there, it just is not easy to find.
It is neither in the "Extensions" or "Package" or "VSSDK" project types, but if you search for "domain" (without any filter on language, platform, or project type) the template pops up with the name "Domain-specific Language Designer".

It is even more confusing, because I was also using the latest Visual Studio 2019 Preview and on that version the template simply does not exist.